# Placeholder not work on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using place holder on text field.Then it not working on Internet explorer. But another browser working correct.

Comment: Can you show us your html code?

Comment: A search for [`ie9 placeholder`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ie9+placeholder) would have yield enough ways to solve this problem